# Why nodejs http request doesn't work when accessing a local served express app?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, requestjs

I have an express REST API app running on 8082. Then I'm trying to do a call from my another app using request:

```
request.post({
    url: 'http://localhost:8082/test',
    method: 'POST',
    json: {
        code: 'Hello'
    }   
}, (err, res, body) => {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(res)
    console.log(body)
})
```

But I'm getting a `502 Bad Gateway` error:

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Does it look like it's looking into Nginx but not to expressjs?

How can I force it to look into my running app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your other app code for the right port, or change the port if nginx is listening on that port.